# if else to check attribute and create new File

Tags: java, jsp

As a newbie struggling with some code to determine whether an attribute is empty and then, within an if else statement create new Files which can then be used outised the if statement.

I have a webcam which the user can select and if this is used to capture a new photo then it 'replaces' a previous image stored in a hash map.

This seems to work

```
String camera = String.valueOf (request.getAttribute("webcamfile"));
```

Then I want to

```
if (camera !=null & camera !="")    // check whether the capture occured
{   
File f=new File(camera);  // if yes create new file contain the capture
}
else
{
File f=new File(itemx.getName());  // if no retrieve original path
}

System.out.println(f);
```

Reuse f elswhere in the jsp

The hash map and f need to be accessible outside of the if statement.
I believe I need to create an empty f outisde of the if and then append to it inside the if statement.

Thoughts on the best way to accomplish this (with the least amount of code) appreciated.

This is what I currently have, if I uncomment the code shown then f's name changes to null (irrespective of what is in camera). Adding statements after itemx.getName seems to 'destroy' the Name.

```
File f=new File(itemx.getName());

//if (camera != null && !camera.isEmpty()) {
//f=new File(camera);
//}

System.out.println(f);
System.out.println(f.toString()); 

File uploadedFile = new File(pageContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/uploads")+"/"+prefix+f.getName());

itemx.write(uploadedFile)
str2="uploads/"+prefix+f.getName();
hash.put(itemx.getFieldName(), str2);
```

Regards
Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize a new File instance (can also be null) outside the if/else scope to be able to access in another place.

```
File f = null;
```

To prevent an Exception to be thrown at your print Statement dont forget to check if "f" is still null before calling println.

inside if:

```
f = new File(camera)
```

inside else:

```
f= new File(xxxx)
```

---

If I understand it right and u want your default file value to be "itemx.getName()" - you have to initialize your File with this value and then overwrite it if request.getAttribute("webcamfile") is not null.

Then you should be writing something like this:

```
String camera = String.valueOf (request.getAttribute("webcamfile"));
File f = new File(itemx.getName());
if (camera != null && !camera.isEmpty()) {
    f=new File(camera);
}
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: Thanks Faber, much appreciated, though I now get str cannot be resolved. Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Sry of course "str" should be "camera" ! I corrected it. Its just a Method u can use on a String to check if a String is empty

Comment: hello @Faber, bizarely (as an AxeIH's code) any code such as 'if' after the File f = new File(itemx.getName() seems to change the original name in the hash map (i.e test.jpg) to null (System.out.println(f) produces null even if camera is null or empty).

Comment: Are you sure that itemx.getName() returns a proper pathname (i.e. test.jpg) at that time in code?  If you print out a File with System.out.println the toString() method is called so it should print out "test.jpg" if the File is correctly created.

Comment: Hello @Faber, yes a standard and a toString produces Male2.jpg (with the current photo being used).  Anything (like an if statement) placed after itemx.getName seems to revert the Name to null. This is beyond my knowledge. I will add the actual code being used to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I like ternary operator for this case

```
File f = new File(camera !=null && !camera.equals("") ? camera : itemx.getName());
```

One line and this will compile now that `f` exist in the scope.

Note :

- use `&&` to prevent a `NullPointerException` in case of `camera == null`
- `String.equals` to compare the value of a String, not `!=`
- `camera.equals("")` is the same as `camera.isEmpty()`

The condition could be reduce too :

```
camera !=null && !camera.equals("")
```

And a quick test to show how it works on [ideone](http://ideone.com/cATlHb)

Comment: Thanks @AxeIH, a much simpler line but get syntax error on token )  after camera, though the syntax seems right. Thoughts?

Comment: @Active, yep, sorry I miscount my parenthesis. I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks again @AxeIH

Comment: Hello @AxeIH, there is no v visible anywhere on the page but your answer was the 'simplest' (in my opinion). Thanks again, I wouldn't make much progress without this forum.

Comment: Sorry @AxeIH, spoke too sson, I need to also check whether camera is Null as well as empty (your line outputs Null into F if camera contains Null)

Comment: Thanks again @AxeIH, somehting not quite right, syntax error on last parenthesis and if I add one in before the first camera the line seems to run but something seems to be converting itemx.getName to Null. If I run File f = new File(itemx.getName()); on its own this part works

Comment: @Active I have the correct count and this work here. Check your syntax (copy it from here again)

Comment: Thanks @AxeIH, syntax now ok but seems to rename the contents of itemx.get(Name) to null (previously picture.jpg)

Comment: File f=new File(itemx.getName());
System.out.println(f);  //Male2.jpg in console
                 
File g = new File(camera !=null && !camera.equals("") ? camera : itemx.getName());
                   
System.out.println(g);  // null in console
System.out.println(camera); /null in console

Comment: @Active Did you checked if it was not `name` that was `null` ? Because with this condition, this is the only possibility.

Comment: @AxeIH My conclusion is that somethng happens to the hash map pointer depending on what code comes after a retrieval, though this may be completely wrong. Leavng just the if test and commenting out the if action still resulted in a null name. Yet I can run multiple itemx.getName commands (without any code after them) and that returns the correct name each time (Male2,jpg). Fiddling with hash map pointers is too complex for me.

Comment: @Active, this is a different problem, [here is a small test](http://ideone.com/cATlHb) with 3 value (`null`, `""` and `"bar"`). You can see the output I get is correct. From what I have, I can't help you, this is a different question (here, it's about and `if-else` condition that works)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (camera !=null && camera !="")
```

Comment: Would be worth expanding your answer and explaining why you feel this code will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Faber and Mr. Laststrinx and to all who responded, seems to be ok now.